# ASP.NET Core MVC Display Templates not rendering

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, display-templates

I'm trying to use [display templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/display-templates?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to change how a `DateTime` is rendered but the default template is always being used.

The model:

```
public class ProgressDetailViewModel : MemberDetailBaseViewModel
{
    // <snip>
    public DateTime? CurrentJourneyStartDate { get; set; }
}
```

Display template:

```
@using DateTime.Extensions;
@model Nullable<System.DateTime>

@if (Model.HasValue)
{
    <span class="form-control">@Model.Value.ToSpecificTimeZone().ToString()</span>
}
<span>Hello from display template</span>
```

The view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CurrentJourneyStartDate)
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.CurrentJourneyStartDate, "DateTime")
```

The display templates *seem* to be in the correct location:

[image: File structure of DisplayTemplate folder]

However the date is always rendered using the default template. I have downloaded the sample from the above link and this works fine when I edit it to include a `DateTime` display template.

Environment:

- .NET 6
- ASP.NET Core MVC
- Runs in Docker on Alpine linux

Why aren't the display templates being picked up?